# unsubscribe button to unsubscribe on the cloud page on a click

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, unsubscriber, cloudpagesurl

I have a use case in which I need to create a button(unsubscribe button) on the cloud page and after a click, the subscriber should get unsubscribed.

How can this be achieved, I have tried using HTML code but that is not fulfilling the use case.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to build two CloudPages.

The first one, will have the unsubscribe button and your subscribers will be taken to that page from a link within the email. Upon clicking the unsubscribe button, your subscribers will be taken to the second CloudPage.

On the second CloudPage, you will need to include the unsubscribe script, which can be either written in AMPscript or Server-Side JavaScript (HTML won’t be sufficient for your use case). Here are some script samples which you can use on the second CloudPage to unsubscribe subscribers: [Unsubscribe and Log an UnsubEvent with a LogUnsubEvent Execute Call](http://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/10/06/unsubscribe-and-log-an-unsubevent-with-a-logunsubevent-execute-call/)

Remember to use the [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) function for rerouting subscribers from the email to the first CloudPage and for the button that takes the to the second CloudPage.